# Titanium Android app crashes upon updating ScrollableView

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

First of all: everything works exactly as intended in iOS.

The issue I believe is some Java object generated by titanium isn't getting a parameter that updates the size of the scrollable view.

Error log:

```
[WARN] :   ResourceType: No known package when getting name for resource     number 0xffffffff
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d57b20)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [674,5584] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 0 Pager id: ffffffff Pager class: class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIScrollableView$1 Problematic adapter: class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIScrollableView$ViewPagerAdapter; Titanium 3.5.0,2015/01/12 15:33,0014f83
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 1, found: 0 Pager id: ffffffff Pager class: class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIScrollableView$1 Problematic adapter: class ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUIScrollableView$ViewPagerAdapter
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:962)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.constrainChild(TiCompositeLayout.java:398)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onMeasure(TiCompositeLayout.java:278)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.constrainChild(TiCompositeLayout.java:398)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onMeasure(TiCompositeLayout.java:278)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.constrainChild(TiCompositeLayout.java:398)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout.onMeasure(TiCompositeLayout.java:278)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[INFO] :   Process: Sending signal. PID: 1280 SIG: 9
```

The crash happens when either directly setting the .views property of a scrollable view or when using .setViews().

Relevant code:

```
//on scrolling of the Years view fill the makes and model views
function populateMake(e){   
$.makeScrollableView.scrollToView(0);
removeAllChildren($.makeScrollableView);

//Generating URL        
var selectedYear = $.yearScrollableView.currentPage; //selected index
var carYearViews = $.yearScrollableView.getViews(); //array of views
var children = carYearViews[selectedYear].getChildren(); //children of the selected year (aka the label w/ the year in it)
var makeYear = children[0].getText();

var url = "www.example.com"; 
var makeViews = [];
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e){
        var yearMakes = [];
        yearMakes = parseMakes(this.responseText); //returns an array of strings

        for(var i = 0; i < yearMakes.length; i++){
            var yearLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                title: "year",
                text: yearMakes[i]
            });
            var view = Ti.UI.createView({
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            });
            view.add(yearLabel);
            makeViews.push(view);
        }
        $.makeScrollableView.setViews(makeViews); //<--- crashes here when scrolling $.yearScrollableView

        populateModel();
    },
    onerror : function (e){
        Ti.API.error("HTTP Error populating makes");
    }
});
client.open("GET", url);
client.send(); 
}
```

And:

```
//populate model when year/make is changed
function populateModel(e){
$.modelScrollableView.scrollToView(0);
removeAllChildren($.modelScrollableView);

var selectedYear = $.yearScrollableView.currentPage; //selected index

var carYearViews = $.yearScrollableView.getViews(); //array of views
var childrenYear = carYearViews[selectedYear].getChildren(); //children of the selected year (aka the label w/ the year in it)
var carYear = childrenYear[0].getText();

var url = "www.totallyafakewebsite.net";
Ti.API.info(url);
var modelViews = [];
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload : function(e){
        var carModels = [];
        carModels = parseModels(this.responseText); //array of strings

        for(var i = 0; i < carModels.length; i++){
            var modelLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                title: "model",
                text: carModels[i]
            });
            var view = Ti.UI.createView({
                backgroundColor: 'blue'
            });
            view.add(modelLabel);
            modelViews.push(view);
        }


        $.modelScrollableView.setViews(modelViews); //<--- this is the crash when scrolling $.makeScrollableView
        //$.modelScrollableView.views = modelViews;   //doesn't work either
    },
    onerror : function (e){
        Ti.API.error("HTTP Error populating models: " + e.error);
    }
});
client.open("GET", url);
client.send();
}
```

These events are triggered when the corresponding scrollable view is scrolled.

Each scrollable view is created in the xml view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own issue:

The reason why this was happening was due to my own removeAllChildren function not working. Because Titanium's function did not work I had to create my own.

The inside of the function looked something like this:

```
$.scrollableView.values = []; //an empty array
```

Instead I used the following code:

```
//Remove old data from $.makeScrollableView
$.makeScrollableView.setCurrentPage(0);
makeViews.length = 0;
```

Setting the current index to 0 and then setting the array length to 0 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

@starlord7, the following statement that you had in your code is not correct ...

```
removeAllChildren($.makeScrollableView);
```

You have to change it to ...

```
$.makeScrollableView.removeAllChildren();
```

Furthermore, I am not entirely sure if it's a good idea to just set the length of the makeViews array to 0. If you have some references in the views that need to be releases, then it will be cleaned to destroy them one by one. This can help you release resources like videos, audios, large images, event listeners, any reference to other views, etc.

Remember, it's so easy to cause huge memory leaks in Android using titanium.